# Importing a class with its dependencies

Tags: python, class, module

I am trying to `import` a class I have created from another file, into my current working file. The class is as follows in this example:

**ClassFile**

```
class example_class:
    
    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.df = yf.download(ticker, start='2020-12-31')
    
    def do_something(self):
        return something
```

Then when I go to import it into my working file, and run the code:

**WorkingFile**

```
import ClassFile
import yfinance as yf

instance = example_class('MSFT')
```

I get the following error:

```
name 'yf' is not defined
```

I understand that `yfinance` is not being imported somewhere but, after researching, I have not been able to understand how to import it.

Essentially, I am trying to understand how to import a class from another file alongside the dependencies within said class.

Comment: Can you think of somewhere else that `import yfinance as yf` could be put, such that it is always right there when the class needs it? (Hint: where would you put it, if the class were the only thing in your project?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel , I've tried both importing it within the class and out of the class however, I  am still met with a undefined 'yf'. It could be a limitation of me using jupyter notebooks however, I don't see why that would be the case

Comment: Did you try putting it at the top of the file that has the class in it? Also, [please show complete errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`. Also please read [mre] and make sure (by **trying it yourself**) that someone else could **copy and paste** the code from the question into the appropriate files, run the code as you describe, and see the exact problem immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import` the symbol where you use it; in `ClassFile`.

```
import yahoofinance as yf

class example_class:
    
    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.df = yf.download(ticker, start='2020-12-31')
    
    def do_something(self):
        return something
```

When you `import` something, it is imported into the current scope, i.e. the current file of code.

In theory, if you left `import ... yf` in `WorkingFile.py`, you could say

```
import WorkingFile

...
    self.df = WorkingFile.yf.download(ticker, start='2020-12-31')
```

though of course in this case, that would create a circular import; and anyway, you don't want to do this - it is completely insane. The entire job of `import` is to bring in something where you actually need it.

The other way around is how you are supposed to use it; the user of `ClassFile` should not need to know or care that the implementation uses `yfinance` internally.  A proper class should encapsulate its internals from its users, and only expose functionality that they directly need.

In some scenarios, you need to compromise; for example, if `ClassFile` is a really thin wrapper around `yfinance` (let's say it inherits from it and adds a new method `sell_MSFT` but otherwise works identically) then of course the user needs to be familiar with `yfinance` anyway, and you can defer to its documentation for most of the functionality.  But still, in that case, the `import yfinance` needs to go where it is actually used; in `ClassFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You either specifically import the class if you want to use its name without the file classifier (ClassFile) or use the Classifier with the function name. You do NOT have to import the depenency modules. ie

```
import ClassFile

instance = ClassFile.example_class('MSFT')
```

or:

```
from ClassFile import example_class

instance = example_class('MSFT')
```

I assume yf is imported or declared somehwere in ClassFile. That is put you r yf import statement in ClassFile

Comment: I think this may be why I am confused. I have tried to import yf in the ClassFile, both within the class, and out of it. Yet, I am still met with 'yf' not being defined

Comment: in ClassFile at the very top put the statement `import yfinance as yf`. Then run your code and post any error messages.